# Slow processing speed of samba

Tags: samba, performance, file-sharing

I use samba for exchanging files within my LAN. The reason I use samba is because there is need to access the server's samba shares from Linux, Windows, and Mac. For exchanging files it works alright. But when I want to get the total content size of a folder with a right-click on the folder and then selecting *Properties*, I have to wait a long time. I believe the reason for that is that the samba client asks for the size of every file and then sums up the sizes contained in the folder. This would represent a lot of communication between server and client and hence result in a longer waiting experience for the user. In my belief, the solution for this is to ask the samba server directly for the folder instead of doing this step locally.

Is there any way to do so?